# unable to print result from switch case in java script

Tags: javascript, html, input, switch-statement, output

I took one input om(obtained marks) and another input mm(total marks), I am trying to calculate the percentage and grade. I got the output for percentage marks but couldn't get the output for grade after I wrote a switch case. Please review the code and let me know my mistake.

```js
function perc() { 
  document.getElementById("perc").value=            (document.getElementById("om").value/document.getElementById("mm").value)*100

  var percentage=document.getElementById("perc").value
  var grade;

  switch(Math.floor(percentage/10)) {
    case 9:grade="outstanding"
      break;
    case 8:grade="very good"
      break;
    case 7:grade="good"
      break;
    case 6:grade="improve well"
      break;
    case 5:grade="average"
      break;
    default:grade="fail"
      break;
  }

  document.getElementById("grade").value=grade;
```

```html
<h1>percentage & grade calculator</h1>
MaxMarks:-<input type="text" id="mm"><br><br>
obtained marks:-<input type="text" id="om"><br><br>
<button type="button" onclick="perc()">SUBMIT</button><br><br>
percentage:-<input type:-"text" id="perc"><br><br>
Grade:-<input type="text" id="grade"><br><br>
```

At first, I got output for percentage after I wrote the code for grade i didn't get any output

Comment: You have a syntax error in the JavaScript code, which is being reported on the browser console.  Always check there for errors.  You should make consistent use of indentation and other whitespace formatting to help you read and understand your own code, so you can more easily find such typos.  Using an IDE can also drastically help in this regard.

Comment: I will take note of these things.thank you

Answer (score 0):

The `perc` function is not closed.
You need to close the curly bracket of the function.
Try this

```html
<html>

<head>
       <title>percentage</title>
</head>
<script>

       function perc() {

              document.getElementById("perc").value = (document.getElementById("om").value / document.getElementById("mm").value) * 100

              var percentage = document.getElementById("perc").value

              var grade;

              switch (Math.floor(percentage / 10)) {
                     case 9: grade = "outstanding"
                            break;
                     case 8: grade = "very good"
                            break;
                     case 7: grade = "good"
                            break;
                     case 6: grade = "improve well"
                            break;
                     case 5: grade = "average"
                            break;
                     default: grade = "fail"
                            break;
              }

              document.getElementById("grade").value = grade;
       } // This is the missing bracket
</script>

<body>
       <h1>percentage & grade calculator</h1>

       MaxMarks:-<input type="text" id="mm"><br><br>

       obtained marks:-<input type="text" id="om"><br><br>

       <button type="button" onclick="perc()">SUBMIT</button><br><br>

       percentage:-<input type:-"text" id="perc"><br><br>

       Grade:-<input type="text" id="grade"><br><br>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you that's a silly mistake from my side